# Several IPs for my VPS

Tags: ip, iptables, vps

I bought vps on santrex.net but can't receive any reply from support. My Problem: I have 5 ip but it pings only 1!!! I can't setup DNS because I need 2 ip minimum .

Could you help me to activate other my IPs?

```
root@spnova:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:b9:4f:19:01
          inet addr:188.72.240.100  Bcast:188.72.240.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:163342 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13585 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:32862185 (32.8 MB)  TX bytes:15189036 (15.1 MB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:b9:4f:19:01
          inet addr:188.72.240.101  Bcast:188.72.240.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:b9:4f:19:01
          inet addr:188.72.240.102  Bcast:188.72.240.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:b9:4f:19:01
          inet addr:188.72.240.103  Bcast:188.72.240.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:b9:4f:19:01
          inet addr:188.72.240.104  Bcast:188.72.240.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:11885 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11885 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:8124693 (8.1 MB)  TX bytes:8124693 (8.1 MB)



root@spnova:~# nano /etc/network/interfaces
# Auto generated eth0 interfaces
auto eth0 lo
iface eth0 inet static
        address 188.72.240.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        up route add -net 188.72.225.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
        up route add default gw 188.72.225.1
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 188.72.240.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 188.72.240.102
        netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
        address 188.72.240.103
        netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
        address 188.72.240.104
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Not really solving your problem but a good advice: Most registries require two name servers for a reason. It is not wise to use the same name server (although with different IP addresses) for your domains. Get a slave name server somewhere else (e. g. http://www.everydns.com/ if you do not want to pay someone; but remember: YGWYPF).

Comment: "can't receive any reply from support" sounds like a good reason to switch VPS provider? Also, I very much agree with joschi regarding actually having *separate* name servers.

Comment: I second the comment by joschi; you do not want to put your secondary DNS on the same host as the primary. I have used the free service from [twisted4life.com](http://www.twisted4life.com/) in the past before I set up my own geographically distributed domain servers.

Comment: Thanks for reply good idea to use other server for second ip.

Answer (score 1):

We won't really be able to help you without knowing what routing/networking setup your provider uses.

If you can't get a reply from support, ditch that provider and go with a reputable provider like [Linode](http://linode.com) (my preference) or [Slicehost](http://slicehost.com) (another well-liked VPS provider). In my experience with Linode (and I've been with them for ~6 years), every support request has been answered within 15 minutes.

Ditch your crappy provider and give your well-earned money to someone who deserves it and who will give you good service.

Comment: in the UK bytemark know what they are doing, check them out. When choosing a provider make sure human support is high on your check list.

Comment: Linode has a London datacenter now :) One of the ~8 linodes I manage is in that datacenter and it performs very well, even for trans-atlantic traffic.